# Python change output format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created this program and I need it to output like this:
[image: this]

How can I do that?

```
n=int(input(""))
L = []
x=0
c=0
while x<=n-1:
    Numero=int(input(""))
    final="*"*Numero,Numero
    L.append(final)
    x=x+1
for elem in L:
        print(elem)
```

Comment: TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found. How to convert from int to str. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elem` is a tuple of a string and an integer number. There are several ways to display it as a string:

```
print(*elem)

print("%s %d" % elem)

print("{} {}".format(*elem))

print(elem[0], elem[1])
```

Comment: One final question why i get None in the last line of the output? https://pastebin.com/f8uwqMe2

Comment: Because your function does not have a `return` and implicitly returns a `None`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format()` to append strings:

```
n=int(input("Please input number"))
r=["*"*int(input("")) for i in range(n)]
for i in r:
    print("{} {}".format(i,len(i)))
```

Output:

```
Please input number4
4
2
3
1
**** 4
** 2
*** 3
* 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to unpack the arguments to the function using `*`. So your print statement would become:

```
print(*elem)
```

See the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) for more information.

```
>>> e = ('****', 4)
>>>> print(e)
('****', 4)
>>> print(*e)
**** 4
```